# What should I be looking out for in a wireless router to support a large number of users?

Tags: wireless

I hope this is the correct place to ask this.

I was placed in charge of the network of a small business. Previously, the number of wireless devices connected to the wireless router was under 20, and as such, a consumer grade router was deemed adequate.
As the company grew, it was estimated that the wireless devices would grow towards 100 with each user carrying 2 or more devices.

I was wondering if there is a good metric to look at for business grade routers or otherwise, to determine what is the maximum number of concurrent users it can support?

Comment: There are no business-grade "wireless routers". Businesses use WAPs (with controllers) and routers separately.

Comment: I see. Would my device count pass the point of critical mass to employ WAPs? Or should I redirect my question at another meta?

Comment: I previously supported high density (thousands of users in a room) WiFi networks with Cisco 5508 wireless controllers and 3702i access points.  Once we got to 100 clients per AP our users suffered poor performance (part of that was interference due to overall density). That is with the best enterprise gear available at the time (3-4 years ago).  I would prefer to keep below 50 devices per enterprise class AP.  I would not consider using consumer grade gear with 50 devices.   In your situation I would suggest a small enterprise-class wireless controller with 2-4 APs.

Comment: You might get away with multiple identical autonomous APs in bridging mode, physically distributed through your facility, serving the same SSID, each with a wired Ethernet connection back to your switch/router (no WiFi mesh!).  Set the frequencies to not overlap (may require turning off channel bonding).  At some point autonomous APs become hard to manage, which is why large deployments now use wireless controllers.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to hire a company with experience to perform a wireless site survey. That will tell you haw many WAPs, the proper location, frequencies, power levels, etc, for each WAP to serve what you need with no radio shadows.